# 0xC0000005 while using QFontDatabase.addApplicationFont()

Tags: python, fonts, pycharm, pyqt6

I use the following code while working with PyQt6 (version 6.5.2):

```py
self.font_id = QFontDatabase.addApplicationFont('conf/font.otf')
self.font_family = QFontDatabase.applicationFontFamilies(font_id)

for name, classtype in self.__dict__.items():
    try:
        classtype.setFont(QFont(self.font_family[0], int(self.base_cfg['Config']['fontSize']), QFont.Weight.Bold))
    except AttributeError:
        pass
```

Whether I run or debug the program in PyCharm, I always get the message "Process finished with exit code -1073741819 (0xC0000005)". But when I comment out the first two lines of the code, the program runs normally.

After many tries, I'm now certain that the **QFontDatabase.addApplicationFont('conf/font.otf')** itself is the minimal reproducible example to me. The script crashes even I only execute these two lines:

```
from PyQt6.QtGui import QFontDatabase
QFontDatabase.addApplicationFont('conf/font.otf')
```

I've tested this across Python 3.9.4/3.10.2/3.11.4, and the situation remains the same. I'm using Windows 11 version 22621.2070. I've searched for relevant information, but haven't found anything useful yet.

I tried **-X dev** Interpreter options in PyCharm Run/Debug Configurations, and I got something like this:

```
Windows fatal exception: access violation

Thread 0x00002a00 (most recent call first):
  File "D:\Software\PyCharm Community Edition 2023.2\plugins\python-ce\helpers\pydev\pydevd.py", line 138 in _on_run
  File "D:\Software\PyCharm Community Edition 2023.2\plugins\python-ce\helpers\pydev\_pydevd_bundle\pydevd_comm.py", line 219 in run
  File "D:\Software\Python\lib\threading.py", line 1009 in _bootstrap_inner
  File "D:\Software\Python\lib\threading.py", line 966 in _bootstrap

Thread 0x00004cd4 (most recent call first):
  File "D:\Software\PyCharm Community Edition 2023.2\plugins\python-ce\helpers\pydev\_pydevd_bundle\pydevd_comm.py", line 293 in _on_run
  File "D:\Software\PyCharm Community Edition 2023.2\plugins\python-ce\helpers\pydev\_pydevd_bundle\pydevd_comm.py", line 219 in run
  File "D:\Software\Python\lib\threading.py", line 1009 in _bootstrap_inner
  File "D:\Software\Python\lib\threading.py", line 966 in _bootstrap

Thread 0x00004728 (most recent call first):
  File "D:\Software\Python\lib\threading.py", line 324 in wait
  File "D:\Software\Python\lib\queue.py", line 180 in get
  File "D:\Software\PyCharm Community Edition 2023.2\plugins\python-ce\helpers\pydev\_pydevd_bundle\pydevd_comm.py", line 368 in _on_run
  File "D:\Software\PyCharm Community Edition 2023.2\plugins\python-ce\helpers\pydev\_pydevd_bundle\pydevd_comm.py", line 219 in run
  File "D:\Software\Python\lib\threading.py", line 1009 in _bootstrap_inner
  File "D:\Software\Python\lib\threading.py", line 966 in _bootstrap
```

Can anyone help me with this?

Comment: If you are not trying to load the font from a resource, i'd try to change "conf/font.otf" to absolute path and see if that triggers the error still..

Comment: Please provide a [mre] and more details on your OS.

Comment: The "QFontDatabase.addApplicationFont('conf/font.otf')" itself is the minimal reproducible example to me. I'm using Windows 11 version 22621.2070 by the way.

Comment: As the name suggests, `addApplicationFont()` adds a font to the *application*, but you are not creating any application at all. At least create an instance of QApplication **before** calling `addApplicationFont()`.

Comment: That's exactly where the problem is! Thanks for pointing this out!

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to the reminder from @musicamante:

> As the name suggests, `addApplicationFont()` adds a font to the application, but you are not creating any application at all. At least create an instance of QApplication **before** calling `addApplicationFont()`.

I indeed made a mistake on this. Here's how the problem happened:

The structure of my app window `gui.py` is like below:

```
from PyQt6.XXX import XXX

class MyMainWindow(QMainWindow):
    font_id = QFontDatabase.addApplicationFont('conf/font.otf')
    font_family = QFontDatabase.applicationFontFamilies(font_id)
    
    def __init__(self):
        # some init process

def main():
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    _ = MyMainWindow()
    sys.exit(app.exec())

if __name__ == '__main':
    main()
```

And, in the main entrance of my app:

```
import gui

gui.main()
```

In the whole process, `addApplicationFont()` was executed **before** `app = QApplication(sys.argv)`. Everything become normal after moving those two lines into the `__init__()` part:

```
class MyMainWindow(QMainWindow):
    
    def __init__(self):
        # some init process
        self.font_id = QFontDatabase.addApplicationFont('conf/font.otf')
        self.font_family = QFontDatabase.applicationFontFamilies(font_id)
```